# Evernote overwrote a Quicktime shortcut

Tags: quicktime, shortcut, evernote

There is a shortcut in Quicktime to start new audio recording that I use

<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
But once I installed Evernote it overwrote the shortcut so now it launches Evernote every time. I have deleted Evernote and now when I open Quicktime and press the shortcut, Mac os 10.10 returns this error:

> There is no application set to open the URL evernote://start/.

My question is how can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you try to trash the quicktime plist and restart.

Comment: Which QuickTime version is it?

Comment: the quicktime version is 10.4

Comment: If you access the New Audio recording from with in QuickTime menu does it work then ?

Comment: It does. It's just the Evernote files that still seam to be on my computer that trigger some action once the shortcut is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Terminal type

```
mdfind evernote
```

Now triple (3x) click on any line that contains evernote (that will select the line)..

Next right click and use Reveal in Finder,that will open new window in Finder and show you that file.

Verify and Delete.

Comment: there was a folder inside application support still left from evernote and it is gone now, thanks

Comment: you are welcome :) mdfind is a good toll to look for stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had to quit the Evernote helper process in Activity monitor. That did the job.